# Prevent utf8_encode() from messing up characters

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding

I use characters like `—` (`&mdash;`) and `°` like in `°C` in some places. A string containing these characters echos weird output with function `utf8_encode()`.

The characters appear properly when I don't process the string with `utf8_encode()`. However, then the function `wp_update_post()` starts throwing error due to encoding mismatch. (I found about this issue from an SO question.)

What is the proper way of displaying these characters on webpages?

Comment: I think you want to convert the string to UTF-8, not interpret it as UTF-8: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php.  There is no "correct way," if the web page content type can support the encoding, you can just use them as a string literal.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBarker. So, `utf8_encode()` does not encode to string to UTF-8?

Comment: Your input is not ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @AlexBarker I have no idea. The input is simply `$string = 'This is a string';`. Is everything ISO-8859-1 by default?

Comment: Is the encoding of `$string` in my previous comment ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @AlexBarker using `mb_convert_encoding()` did seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, my reply was confusing.  utf8_encode is interpreting the ISO-8859-1 string as UTF8, not converting.  "This function converts the string data from the ISO-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8."  That is why `var_dump(utf8_encode("TEST°")) == "TESTÂ°"`

Comment: @AlexBarker Are simple strings that we create in PHP interpreted as `ISO-8859-1` encoding by default?

Comment: I cannot find any official mention of this.  Historically, it's been a mixed bag.  I would assume ASCII only unless you are using mb_ functions or RAW binary data.  Technically, the PHP string should be binary safe, so following PHP convention, it will be in what ever encoding you use it as.  Think about it like a signed int, the computer doesn't know the difference between the signed and unsigned binary data, it is all about how you interpret that binary data in your program.

Comment: @AlexBarker In my case, I did not specify any encoding anywhere for the string. I did not use any of the `mb_` functions or `utf8_encode()` etc. So, this means that the `wp_update_post()` function assumed that the string was ASCII and threw an error because it only wants UTF-8 encoded strings?

Comment: @AlexBarker Thanks for being so patient. :)

Comment: NP, I have posted the complete answer below for space reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know what the encoding of binary string is and use [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) instead of assuming the data is already in ISO-8859-1 format by using `utf8_encode()`

There is no "correct way," if the web page content type can support the encoding via the Content-Type header, you can just use them as a string literal.

Technically, the PHP string should be binary safe, so following PHP convention, it will be in what ever encoding you use it as. Think about it like a signed int, the computer doesn't know the difference between signed and unsigned binary data, it is all about how you interpret that binary data in your program.

You are specifying the encoding by using `utf8_encode()`, you just didn't realize you did.  For example, lets say you have a binary string `$s = "TEST°";`  The string is currently binary in your program, it could have no ASCII and be total gibberish, like you read the first 5 bytes of an exe file.  When you called `utf8_encode($s)` you told PHP that it could go ahead and assume `$s` is an ISO-8859-1 string and convert `$s` to UTF-8 based on that assumption. This is the same as `mb_convert_encoding("TEST°", "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1")`. The confusion is coming about because "°" is not a valid ISO-8859-1 value, it is 0xC2B0 because I copied it from the web browser which is already using UTF-8 to represent this value.  The 8859-1 value for degree is 0xB0, so `var_dump(mb_convert_encoding("TEST" . chr(0xB0), "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1"))` does indeed produce the correct result where 0xB0 is converted to 0xC2B0: TEST°

If you do not specify the 3rd parameter to `mb_convert_encoding()` the value of [mb_internal_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) will be used by default.  This default value is not guaranteed to be UTF-8, and you should not assume the binary string to be in UTF-8.  You should know what encoding that data is in. If it came from the browser, it told you in the Content-Type; which itself is assumed to be UTF-8 in most cases but again not guaranteed.  If the data is related to the RDBMS, it probably already [did this encoding conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation.html) for you.